# html5 form validation not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get form validation working with IE9. I can get the basics working but form validation is not working.

In the code below the dropdown works fine in IE9, so I know bootstrap and jquery is working, but the form performs no validation (I.e required field not failing when empty in IE9). When I run it in IE11 all is well.

I presumed the html5 shiv with modernizr and respond would fix this.

What is wrong?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    </STYLE>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container" >
          <form class="form-signin"  METHOD="post" ACTION="agentLogin.asp">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Portal login</h2>
            <label for="username" class="sr-only">User ID</label>
            <input type="email" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" required autofocus>
            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    <div class = "dropdown">
       <button type = "button" class = "btn dropdown-toggle" id = "dropdownMenu1" data-toggle = "dropdown">
          Topics
          <span class = "caret"></span>
       </button>

       <ul class = "dropdown-menu" role = "menu" aria-labelledby = "dropdownMenu1">
          <li role = "presentation">
             <a role = "menuitem" tabindex = "-1" href = "#">Java</a>
          </li>

          <li role = "presentation">
             <a role = "menuitem" tabindex = "-1" href = "#">Data Mining</a>
          </li>

          <li role = "presentation">
             <a role = "menuitem" tabindex = "-1" href = "#">
                Data Communication/Networking
             </a>
          </li>

          <li role = "presentation" class = "divider"></li>

          <li role = "presentation">
             <a role = "menuitem" tabindex = "-1" href = "#">Separated link</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="js/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="js/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in head:

`<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that, I don't have internet at this site (it's internal page), hence why I used local files.

Comment: You can download file through dev url. And save in you project and provide location of that file in sec...